# Getting a js file in the HTML head is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script "test.js". The only contents of test.js are `console.log('hi from the script!')`. Why does this message not show up in my js console in chrome or firefox?

The `network` panel's `response` shows the correct script. So file location is correct.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javscript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('hello?');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the typo in `type="text/jav***a***script` just here or in code as well ?

Comment: Then you could accept the answer of ryanbrill.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in the script type. It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```